Integral solutions $a$, $b$ for given integer $d$ to $((a+b)-2d)^2 = 4(ab-1)\text{.}$
I've tried finding solutions for some integers $d$ such as $d = 1,5, 13, 29, 37$ and came to the observation that there are polynomial solutions $(a,b)$ to this equation. However, the necessary condition solvability of this equation is still unclear to me and on how these computations of the polynomials can be justified.
As an example, for $d= 1$, we have the solution
$$  (a,b) = (2n^2+2n+1, 2n^2 - 2n +1)  $$
for integer $n$.


Integral solutions $a$, $b$ for given integer $d$ to $((a+b)-2d)^2 = 4(ab-1)\text{.}$

Alternative approach: 
Interpret the problem as a 2nd degree polynomial equation in $~a.$
$$(a^2 + 2ab + b^2) - 4d(a+b) + 4d^2 = 4ab - 4 \iff $$
$$a^2(1) + a(-2b - 4d) + (b^2 - 4db + 4d^2 + 4) = 0 \iff $$
$$a = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~(2b + 4d) \\
\pm \sqrt{ ~[ ~4b^2 + 16bd + 16d^2 ~] - [ ~4 \times (b^2 - 4db + 4d^2 + 4) ~] ~} ~\right] $$
$$ \iff $$
$$a = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~(2b + 4d) \pm \sqrt{ ~[ ~32bd - 16~] ~} ~\right] \iff $$
$$a = (b + 2d) \pm 2\sqrt{ ~2bd - 1 ~}. \tag1 $$
First of all, since the original problem is symmetric in the variables $~a,b,~$ you have that $~a = n_1, ~b = n_2~$ will be a solution if and only if $~a = n_2, ~b = n_1~$ is also a solution.
Given that, from (1) above, with $~d~$ fixed, all solutions will be given by
$$2bd - 1 = n^2 ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}} \iff (n^2 + 1) = 2bd. \tag2 $$
From (2) above, $~n~$ must be odd, which implies that $~n > 0.$ 
This implies that $~n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}.~$ 
This implies that $~2bd \equiv 2 \pmod{4}.~$ 
This implies that $~b,d~$ must both be odd.
So, $~d~$ must be some factor of one of the elements in $~\dfrac{n^2 + 1}{2} \in \{1, 5, 13, 25, 41, \cdots \},~$
with $~\displaystyle b = \dfrac{n^2 + 1}{2d}, ~a = (b + 2d) \pm 2\sqrt{ ~2bd - 1 ~} = (b + 2d) \pm 2n.$

I've come up with a similar approach but mine lacks the condition for $d$ so that the equation is solvable in the integers. Thank you for your answer.
